# Prove that the resolvent set is open

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $T$ be an operator with domain $D(T)\subset \mathcal H$, where $\mathcal H$ is an Hilbert space. I tried to prove that the resolvent set
$$\rho(T)= \{ \mu \in \mathbb C \mid (\mu - T)^{-1}: \mathcal H \to D(T) \text{ exists and is bounded} \}.$$
So, let $\lambda\in \rho(T)$ and $\varepsilon \in \mathbb C$ with small absolute value. We want to prove that $\lambda +\varepsilon \in \rho(T)$.

Let  $T_\lambda := \lambda -T$ and in the same way we define $T_{\lambda + \varepsilon}$. At first we notice that
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
\infty >||T_\lambda ^{-1}|| = \sup_{\substack{u\in \mathcal H}} \frac {||T_\lambda ^{-1}u||}{||u||}=\sup_{u\in D(T)}\frac{||u||}{||T_\lambda u|| }= \frac{1}{\inf _{\substack{ u \in D(T)\\||u||=1}}||T_\lambda u||}.
\end{equation}
Therefore, $T_\lambda$ is bounded from below, i.e. there is some $C>0$ with $||T_\lambda u||> C||u||$. We take now $T_{\lambda +\varepsilon}$ and we want to show that $T_{\lambda+\varepsilon}:D(T)\to \mathcal H$ is bijective and the inverse is bounded. It follows directly
$$||T_{\lambda+\varepsilon} u || = ||T_\lambda u +\varepsilon u|| \geq || T_\lambda u ||-|\varepsilon|\;||u||\geq(C-|\varepsilon|)\;||u||.$$
We have chosen $|\varepsilon|$ to be small, so $T_{\lambda+\varepsilon}$ is also bounded from below. Hence $T_{\lambda + \varepsilon}$ is injective and analogously to $(1)$ we have that $T_{\lambda + \varepsilon}^{-1}$ is also bounded. It remains to prove that $T_{\lambda + \varepsilon}$ is surjective, but sadly I was not able to prove it.

I would be happy for any help.

Comment: @Calvin Khor The operator $T$ considered in this question is unbounded. The operators $(\lambda I-T)^{-1}$ for $\lambda\in \varrho(T)$ are not surjective.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc thank you for the information!

Comment: The operator $T$ should be closed, or at least closable. See Proposition 4.2.1 https://www.mat.tuhh.de/veranstaltungen/isem23/_media/lecture_02.pdf

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc We can assume that $T$ is closed. If $T$ is not closed, then $\rho(T)=\emptyset$  and therefore open.

Comment: @Salfalur  That's a trivial case. It still can be empty even if $T$ is closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $\lambda\in\rho(T)$. Let $\epsilon$ be a small complex number, and consider
\begin{align}
     ((\lambda+\epsilon)I-T)^{-1}&=((\lambda I-T)+\epsilon I)^{-1} \\
    &=((\lambda I-T)(I+\epsilon(\lambda I-T)^{-1}))^{-1} \\
    &=(I+\epsilon(\lambda I-T)^{-1})^{-1}(\lambda I-T)^{-1} \\
    &=\left[\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\epsilon^n((\lambda I-A)^{-1})^{n}\right](\lambda I-T)^{-1} \\
  &=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}\epsilon^{n}((\lambda I-A)^{-1})^{n+1}.
\end{align}
Everything converges nicely and gives you an actual inverse provided $\epsilon\in\mathbb{C}$ is chosen small enough that
$$
        |\epsilon|\|(\lambda I-A)^{-1}\| < 1.
$$
Therefore, the resolvent set of $T$ is open.

Comment: I think in the third row there is a $\,^{-1}$ missing. But thanks for this solution.

Comment: @Salfalur - thank you. i fixed that now.